# How to add leading zeros in Excel (timestamp with ms has no leading zeroes)

Tags: excel, timestamp

I’m still having a grave problem with some files. It’s a rather stupid problem, but I’ve been working at it for quite some time and can’t find a solution.
I need leading zeroes in the time stamps, at least on the ms level.
The timestamps that my software makes always look like this: (example)

`9:55:1:19` (that is 9h, 55min, 1sec, 19 ms)

while what I need would look like

`09:55:01:019`

It’s no problem to make a conversion in Excel. I use

`=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(G2;":";",";3))`

but I always get

`09:55:01:190` (190ms!!)

Thus the milliseconds are always read like comma values, which is understandable from the software’s point of view.

I'd like a solution that either appends the correct values to the end of each row in a new column or directly changes the values in the original column (D) to the correct values. (Appending is OK because my other scripts work that way already!)

Can you help out really quickly?

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3ch6ikddplnyjgg/vUfnVgbbzH here's an example file

Comment: The values in your `msec` column are not recognised by Excel as times - it is treating them as if they were text.  Do you have the raw time values available anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

With a value in **A1** like:

0.413206238

the formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss.000"),".",":")
```

will display:

09:55:01:019

**EDIT#1:**

Or if you want to convert the values in column **D**, in place.  Select the cells and run this small macro:

```
Sub FFormat()
    Dim r As Range, L As Long, U As Long
    For Each r In Selection
        ary = Split(r.Text, ":")
        U = UBound(ary)
        L = LBound(ary)
        For i = L To U
            If Len(ary(i)) = 1 Then
                ary(i) = "0" & ary(i)
            End If
        Next i
        If Len(ary(U)) = 2 Then
            ary(U) = "0" & ary(U)
        End If
        r.Value = Join(ary, ":")
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the original in R12 (my example) is text, you can enter this big formula: :)

```
=TEXT(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(R12;":";REPT(" ";20));4);"00") & ":"&TEXT(MID(SUBSTITUTE(R12;":";REPT(" ";20));14;20);"00") & ":" & TEXT(MID(SUBSTITUTE(R12;":";REPT(" ";20));34;20);"00") & ":" & TEXT(MID(SUBSTITUTE(R12;":";REPT(" ";20));54;20);"000")
```

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace field separator "; " by ","

Answer (score 0):

Your data in column G has a leading space - this formula in a new column should convert to a valid time value whether you have leading spaces or not

`=LEFT(TRIM(G2);FIND("^";SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(G2);":";"^";3))-1)+LOOKUP(1000;RIGHT(G2;{1;2;3})+0)/86400000`

format as [h]:mm:ss.000

This will cope with single or double digit milliseconds, assumes that if there are no milliseconds you will still have third : followed by a zero. Also copes with single digit hours, minutes or seconds